# SSIS VS 2019 - Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject'

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssis-2019

I have an SSIS package created in Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.28) with Data Tools Integration Services 3.16 (16.11.28). I using an ADO.NET connection manager for sources and destinations in the Data Flow as well as an OLE DB connection manager for executing SQL statements in the Control Flow.

When I run the package from Visual studio, I get the *error* below, **HOWEVER**, when I deploy the package to our SQL server, it executes successfully.

I have verified I am running in 32-bit mode (local via Run64bitRuntime->set to false, and on SQL), have verified I have the correct target SQL version (2016), there are no script tasks in the package, and I have rebuilt the package repeatedly.

Does anyone have any additional thoughts on this error and how I might resolve it?

*Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.Sql2016.IDTSApplication130'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{77A93073-6272-4FAC-BDB5-0C589385701C}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)). (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)*